# How to filter my Favorites with tags?

Tags: support, tags, bookmarks, tag-watching

I have 200+ questions marked as Favorites which belongs to multiple tag categories like angular2, asp.net-core etc

When I go to Favorites tab, I get all Favorites list. I would like to filter this list with technical tags so that I can look into my Favorites list + specific tag.

Examples:

- My Favorites + angular2
- My Favorites + asp.net-core

How do I filter my Favorites list along with tags?